# Как использовать apply() функцию после rolling() с method="table"

Tags: python, pandas

Я пытаюсь прогнать DataFrame с 5 колонками через функцию rolling() и применить к ней apply(). **Однако получается так, что при попадании в apply(x) входящий аргумент x имеет вид строки вместо таблицы, как мне добиться передачи в apply(x) таблицы?**

```
def squared_with_numba_cache(x):
    # Тяжелые вычисления
    return # новый вид строки в DatFrame

df = pd.read_csv(path, header=0,
                 dtype=
{'open_time': int32, 'open': float16, 'high': float16, 'low': float16, 'close': float16}
                 ).fillna(0)

df1 = df.rolling(window=3,min_periods=3, method='table')
df1.apply(squared_with_numba_cache, engine='cython')
```

Моя цель: прогнать DataFrame через rolling() и применить к ней engine=numba или engine=cython. В функции ожидаю фрагмент DataFrame с размером window, далее совершаю манипуляции с этим фрагментом и возвращаю 1 строку (что-то по типу агрегирования по скользящему окну)

**Идеально, если это будет реализовано вместе с DASK - главное скорость обработки.**

Comment: Вы один вопрос задайте какой-то. а то у вас вопрос из серии "дайте воды, а то так есть хочется, что переночевать негде". сократите до вопроса "почему rolling возвращает строку вместо таблицы в этом коде", например.

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/44825

Comment: @strawdog
 Спасибо за ответ, я его отредактировал. Ссылка на гитхаб - это не то, что мне нужно